# JDK Error "This app can't run on your PC"

Tags: java

I have been trying to download JDK 10.0.1 on my new PC (Windows 10). I keep getting the same error "This app can't run on your PC, to find a version of your PC check with the software publisher". I have tried uninstalling and re-downloading JDK, but the same error keeps showing up. What can I do?

Edit: My PC has a 64-bit operator

Comment: Maybe start by telling is something about your pc and windows version (32 bits, 64 bits, ...) and the exact JDK version you downloaded. I'm suggesting this because trying to run 64 bits SW on a 32 bits platform is one of the common causes of that error.

Comment: Did you try this? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/install/installation-jdk-and-jre-microsoft-windows-platforms.htm#JSJIG-GUID-A740535E-9F97-448C-A141-B95BF1688E6F

Answer (score 0):

Download the correct JDK version: jdk-10.0.1_windows-x64_bin.exe.

Comment: That is the version I downloaded

Comment: I have same problem running Win10 1800 build using chocolatey.